# Evitar inserción de registros duplicados en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy desarrollando un windowsService en C# que inserta unos registros a una BD MySql, necesito evitar que se inserten registros duplicados, mi tabla consta de los siguientes campos:

```
ID -- CODIGO -- VALOR --- FECHA
```

Puede darse que varios registros tengan la misma fecha, el mismo código o el mismo valor pero en ningún caso habría dos registros con los 3 campos iguales, como podría evitar que un registro así sea insertado/guardado?

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste con un primary key?

Comment: El PK es el ID, que autoincrementable, pero aun asi deberia poder evitar registros con los 3 siguientes campos exactamente iguales a uno previamente insertado

Comment: Y cual es el probnlema? porque eso no es un problema... o queres una solucion desde la base de datos?

Comment: lo que veo es que quiere que no se repita tendría que realizar una consulta con los datos que va a insertar, y si no encuentra ninguno en común, respectivamente enviar los datos.

Comment: via programa realiza un select a con los datos ingresados, si no estan ahi recien realiza el insert, si no los descartas

Comment: En el caso de que fueran pocos datos creeria que haciendo un SELECT COUNT > 0 bastaria, pero el tema es que puedo llegar a insertar miles de registros y entonces tendria que hacer esas miles de validaciones

Comment: Estas utilizando EntityFramework como ORM?

Comment: No, no utilizo ningún ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756689/avoiding-inserting-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE (
`CODIGO` ,
`VALOR` ,
`FECHA`
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado de esta forma.